# remote rejected error in submitting patchset to gerrit via git review

Tags: git, gerrit, gitblit, git-review

I'm struggling to push changes to Gerrit by git review command.

Till now, I've performed the following steps:

1. Installed a Gitblit server on my local pc as per [official documentation](http://gitblit.com/setup_go.html).
2. Installed Gerrit as per [this tutorial](https://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Gerrit/Tutorial#Push_your_change_set_to_Gerrit).

Now, to push the changes for review, I performed the following operations.

```
git clone http://admin@localhost:8008/r/testrepo.git
```

*modified some files*

```
git add .
git commit -m 'my_trial_commit'
```

Everything worked fine till now, but when I run the `git review -R` for submitting new changes for review, I get the following error.

```
git review -R
To http://localhost:8008/r/testrepo.git
! [remote rejected] HEAD -> refs/for/master (testrepo.git is not configured to receive patchsets)
error: failed to push some refs to 'http://admin@localhost:8008/r/testrepo.git'
```

Comment: I met this question yesterday when pushing my code:   'testrepo.git is not configured to receive patchsets', but I have no idea how to handle it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you're pushing to GitBlit, not Gerrit, because the error comes [from GitBlit code](https://github.com/gitblit/gitblit/blob/41e6a701953c6f3ec0c4b2375426e4205a1c6a00/src/main/java/com/gitblit/git/GitblitReceivePack.java#L328). Try again, pushing to the Gerrit HTTP or SSH port.

Also, why GitBlit? The recommended (and supported) code repository browser is *Gitiles* (included as core plugin since 3.0).

Comment: I have a Gitblit repository already setup for my team and it will not be feasible to migrate to a different repo. Moreover, where can I get the Gerrit url string (HTTP/SSH port) that you mentioned? Please bear with me if that's a layman question, as I've just started out with gerrit code review.

Comment: Let's take one step back. If you're using Gerrit, Gerrit should be hosting the repositories and you'll be pushing and fetching from Gerrit. It seems that you're asking for a solution to host repositories in GitBlit, but using Gerrit as review tool. That's not how it works. In Gerrit, GitBlit can be installed as a plugin for code browsing, but it's unmaintained. URLs for fetching/pushing can be seen in the Gerrit Web UI, see project listing.

Comment: Okay makes sense, thanks for the confirmation. I'll then migrate from Gitblit to another repository for code storage.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a need for separate code hosting (although I agree with Gert, it'll be easier on you to just use gitiles) ... Then you might want to add a .gitreview file to your repo. The .gitreview file can point to the gerrit server. For instance:

https://opendev.org/zuul/zuul/src/branch/master/.gitreview

```
[gerrit]
host=review.opendev.org
port=29418
project=zuul/zuul.git
```

Is the zuul gitreview file - which allows cloning zuul from https://opendev.org/zuul/zuul - but let's git-review know that the gerrit for zuul is at review.opendev.org.